# Limit of $\sum (-1)^ {\log \log n }$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, characters

Are there results, or can someone point me to reading, on computations of the following sort:

$\lim_n \sum_{2 \le x\le n} (-1)^ { \log \log x }$

It would seem that there is reason to believe this should be something like $-\log(n)$. For example, see the graphic on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315775/on-the-number-of-integers-with-an-even-number-of-distinct-prime-factors/3303295#3303295) which is the visual representation of $\sum_x (-1)^{\omega(x)}$ which for large $x$ is like $\sum_x (-1)^{\log \log (x)} = \sum_x e^{i \cdot \pi\cdot \log \log x }$. From the picture expectation, this looks something like $- \log n$.

To start, we note that we can reduce

$\sum_{2 \le x\le n} e^{i \cdot \pi\cdot \log \log x } = \sum_{2 \le x\le n} \log(x)^{i \cdot \pi} $.

Now this looks like it's related to a "more general zeta function" $\zeta (\log (n), -i\pi)$ (As opposed to the "standard" $\zeta(n,-i\pi)$.

From here, it would seem that the problem is likely out of reach from basically a college undergrad math student. Any textbooks/links for approaching this (hopefully that can ease me into it) would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Presumably 'cis' means $\exp(i\cdot) : t \mapsto \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$, so why not say that?  Also, does $\lim_n \sum_n$ mean $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty$?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: The limit will not exist. $\log \log n$ grows so slowly that the sum will be overwhelmingly close to $n(-1)^{\log\log n}$.

Comment: Actually, log log x - 1 is log log (x^(1/e)), so there will be some small cancellation/deviation. Say the sum is more like (n-n^{1/e})(-1)^{log log (n/2)), or something similar. Gerhard "There With A Delicate Touch" Paseman, 2019.07.25.

Comment: Well, at least $\int_3^\infty \exp(i\pi\log\log x)\;dx$ diverges.

Comment: If you’re trying to estimate \sum z^{\omega(n)} by substituting \log \log n for \omega(n) you’re going to get wrong answers, even taking z = 2 fails. (The point is that, first off, there are huge deviations (like \sqrt{\log\log n}) from the mean, and, second off, the function z^{\omega(n)} changes by a ton even when there are small deviations.) The growth rate of \sum_{n\leq X} z^{\omega(n)} is X (\log X)^{z-1}, even for complex z, though I don’t remember the hypotheses on z off the top of my head. Look up the Selberg-Delange method. Hope that helps!!